# How to Create a User Control with Image and Text

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, user-controls

Essentially I am trying to mimic the same look as one of the images below with the opaque TextBlock overlay

[image]

What I have now in my UserControl is

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Image Grid.Row="0" Margin="0" Source="{Binding Bitmap}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Text}" Margin="0"
               HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
               Foreground="Black"
               TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
</Grid>
```

So I've tried playing around with the layout but cannot seem to match it correctly. I've tried placing both in Grid.Row="0" which had no effect either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you want to mimic the picture you could do something like this;

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>

   <Image Grid.RowSpan="2" Source="{Binding Bitmap}" 
          Stretch="UniformToFill"/>

   <Border Grid.Row="1" 
           Background="#80000000" Padding="5">

          <TextBlock Text="Blah" 
                     Foreground="White"
                     TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
   </Border>
</Grid>
```

Or could set your image as the Grid Background, or swap the Border with a Rectangle and just throw it and the TextBlock in the same row, there's several ways to accomplish it. Hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: I went with your method, which worked great. Thanks. Can you explain why I could not accomplish this with only placing the TextBlock in Grid 1, but it worked when the TextBlock was nested in the Border?

Comment: I think your culprit was more that the image only consumed Row0 instead of having a RowSpan=2 so the Text would overlay it.